# Have working headphone controller under Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, audio

I have headphones with a controller (+/- volume, play/pause). They work when using an iPad. My question is if it's possible to make it work under Fedora 16  (using GNOME 3)?

I assume some drivers are needed for this, but would this be headphone specific (I'm a newcomer to this world so I'm not completely sure about this)?

Comment: Which headphones? How are they connected to your computer/Ipad?

Comment: [This site provides details on how this can work cable-wise](http://www.wisebread.com/build-a-cable-to-control-your-android-phone-while-you-drive)... no idea if there's a standard.  Interesting question.

Comment: Those are headphones with a 3.5 mm jack with 4 conductors. So I guess my question should have been if my computer is compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be completely up to the hardware, since it relies on having an extra connection on the plug. Most PCs don't have hardware capable of capturing the signal since they only have 3 connections, not 4.

Comment: There are quite a few laptops with TRRS connectors, e.g. MacBook, HP Envy, Lenovo W. The additional connection is often used for a microphone, so I'm not sure how this would work with controls.

Comment: I have a Asus eee pc 1215N, which a quick google search suggests is not compatible with the controls. So I probably can't use the controls unless I change the audio connection.. I guess that might involve changing the motherboard :p